# Asp net MVC5 - Application only access local database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, database-connection

Created a project with Asp Net [mvc5](/questions/tagged/mvc5)
Dont use migration because the database is unchangeable. 
The only thing that is not standard in this project is that the user id is an int.

Application works well locally, accessing database. Without warnings.

Then I tried to change configurations to access an external database with:

`web.config` show this connection string:

---

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
        connectionString="Server=xyz; Database=test_db; User Id=xyz; password= xyz"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And ApplicationDbContext got database thru this:

---

```
private static string GetDataBaseName()
        {
            string configName = "DefaultConnection";
            ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[configName];
            if (mySetting == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySetting.ConnectionString))
                throw new System.Exception("cannot connect database");
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlconection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(mySetting.ToString());

            return sqlconection.InitialCatalog;
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(): base(GetDataBaseName()){}
```

It seems to work but when I enter data into the database through the application, the data appears in the local database.

As if the application was not using the connection string.

Any idea?

Comment: you might be accessing different connection string pointing to local database some where in your application. need to debug and resolve.

Comment: I discovered the problem. My GetDatabaseName method returns only the name of the database taken from the connection string.
When trying to connect the database with only the name, the application searched the database in the local repository. 
As I was using the application on a provider the connection string had to be used completely to actually find the database.
So just commented the GetDatabaseName method and used the connection string.

Comment: good that you found issue and resolve. let me know if you need any help